# как загрузить картинку в локальню сети в виде url python (discord py)

Tags: python

у меня есть на пк картинка и я хочу чтобы бот на питоне её показал, но бот воспринимает только url ссылки

Answer (score 0):

Можно картинку залить на какой-нибудь ресурс, по типу imgur (правда, я не уверен, что сейчас в России можно на него загружать, поэтому можно просто вбить в поисковике "хост изображений" или "image hosting"). Либо можно воспользоваться ресурсами discord'а и создать пустой групповой чат и туда посылать нужные сообщения, затем скопировать ссылку посланного изображения.

Comment: я как то делал так что картинка была в локальной сети(localhost что то такое)